# Select elements from a matrix in R all at once

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I have a `row vector` and a `column vector` say c(1,2), c(7,100). I want to extract (1,7), (2,100).

Out, I find `Matrix[row, column]` will return a cross-product thing not just a vector of two numbers.

What should I do?

Comment: I would read `?matrix` and `?'['`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 column subsetting matrices inside `[`:

```
mx <- matrix(1:200, nrow=2)
mx[cbind(c(1, 2), c(7, 100))]
```

produces:

```
[1]  13 200
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to exploit the feature that if `m` is a matrix containing the row/col indices required, then subsetting by passing `m` as argument `i` of `[` gives the desired behaviour. From `?'['`

```
i, j, ...: indices specifying elements to extract or replace.

          .... snipped ....

          When indexing arrays by ‘[’ a single argument ‘i’ can be a
          matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of ‘x’;
          the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to
          the sets of indices in each row of ‘i’.
```

Here is an example

```
rv <- 1:2
cv <- 3:4
mat <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)

mat[cbind(rv, cv)]

R> cbind(rv, cv)
     rv cv
[1,]  1  3
[2,]  2  4
R> mat[cbind(rv, cv)]
[1] 11 17
```